# Can I run mediawiki and wordpress on a chromebook by using developer mode?

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os, wordpress, chromebook, mediawiki

On my chromebook, is it possible to download and install apache, php, and mysql from developer mode's terminal, for the purposes of running mediawiki and wordpress?

Comment: No, you'll have use something like [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) to install Ubuntu first & then install your standard LAMP stack

Comment: @Sathya, why is that? As far as I understand, developer mode grants access to a linux terminal, and a linux terminal can download and install programs. Is developer mode's terminal limited somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> @Sathya, why is that? As far as I understand, developer mode grants access to a linux terminal, and a linux terminal can download and install programs. Is developer mode's terminal limited somehow?

That is basically true, there are wget and curl to download content and from there you are mostly on your own. There are no pre-compiled or source code packages like on typical Linux distributions as on Fedora or Arch Linux and you don't have write permissions to typical directories like `/usr`, so you have to change the installation prefix to another location. In theory it's possible doing a mostly [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) thing with heavy modifications but it's easier to get a common Linux distribution in a chroot or a separate partition to install these packages.

Chromebooks are appliances like early home routers until OpenWRT came along and offered packages to greatly extend functionality.